# Is it possible to find/replace some characters in a file using some bash commands?

Tags: bash, replace, find, command, yaml

I would like to find if this file /path/to/file/profile.yaml contains the folowing values:

```
    Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl: 0
    Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::CurlSSL: 0
```

and if yes replace the zeros with 1 like this:

```
    Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl: 1
    Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::CurlSSL: 1
```

and all this in a bash command!

How can I do that ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, bash can't do this; however it can be easily done with *ed*, *sed* (with the proprietary -i flag), *awk*. You can also do it in bash by writing to a temporary file and then replacing the original with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sed`.  e.g.:

```
sed -i 's/Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl: 0/Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl: 1/' myfile.txt
```

As @kojiro points out, `-i` is not portable, so you can always do this:

```
sed 's/Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl: 0/Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl: 1/' myfile.txt > tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt myfile.txt
```

Comment: This will output the changed results, but will not change the original file. (And keep in mind sed -i is not portable.)

Comment: `-i` never outputs anything. It makes changes in the file if the match is found with the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

This should work -

```
sed -r 's/(Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl(SSL)?:) 0/\1 1/' yourfile
```

You can either `re-direct` the output to another file or do `-i` for in-file substitution.

Answer (score 2):

To change both lines at one go (and redirect to another file) you can also use perl:

```
perl -pe 's/Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl(SSL)*: 0/Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl$1: 1/' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by 'a bash command', you mean a command you can execute from the bash prompt; if so, then you can use sed to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If it's YAML, then use a proper YAML module for this.  A language like Python (and I'm sure many others) have YAML modules available.  You probably already have Python installed; you'll need to add a YAML package like http://pyyaml.org/.

```
import yaml
with open("some_file","r") as source:
    objects= yaml.load( source )
# change your Cpanel::Easy::PHP5::Curl values
with open("revised_file","w") as target:
    yaml.dump( objects )
```

The only "hard" part about this is the namespace hierarchy that is being used.  It's not clear how this will wind up represented in Python.  You might need to define some packages and classes that reflect the namespace information.